# Remove white background image css

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have `header` element and 50x50 png image in it. Image loaded with css:

```
#header{
  width: 50px;
  height 50px;
  background: url("/static/img/image.png") no-repeat;
}
```

When page loading all displaying normally. When i reduce the size of browser window near the image appears white background. How to remove it?

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Doesn't help

Thank you.

Comment: How about `background: url("/static/img/image.png") no-repeat transparent;`?

Comment: what's the image size? what's around header?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 background: transparent url("/static/img/image.png") center center no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code might be border issue..

```
img{border:0 none;}
```